# How to select an element in selenium which have its ID autogenerated dynamically everytime but always ends with a particular string

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

eg: these are the format of IDs generated for that element.
d43046e142
d43094e142
d43142e142

Comment: Please add your Html for that element

Comment: share the relevant HTML and your desire output.

Comment: <input type="text" name="filter_field" id="d50233e142" value="" size="30" maxlength="" onkeypress="return handleEnter(event, &quot;odf.browsePageFilter&quot;, &quot;browseObject&quot;)" class="ppm_field formFieldNoWidth" accept="">

Comment: I would suggest you to go with any other attribute rather than depending on ID , It'd be highly unstable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write **cssSelector** for that :

Assuming **HTML** is :

```
<div class="d43046e142 d43094e142 d43142e142 static"/>
```

So, if you think **static** is **constant**, then you can write **cssSelector** as :

```
div[class$='static']
```

**Xpath** would be :

```
//div[contains(@class,'static')]
```

**UPDATE**

As per the **HTML** you have shared :

**Xpath** : `//input[contains(@id,'e142')]`

**Code** :  `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[contains(@id,'e142')]')`

**cssSelector** : `input[id$='e142']`

I would suggest you to go with any other attribute rather than depending on **ID** , It'd be highly unstable as it contains too much numeric.

Comment: No actually those are some of the dynamically generated element id.

Comment: Here u can see that every id ends with "e142", so i just want something like Murthi did. Just want to select an element with an id ending with "e142"

Comment: for that replace static in my answer with your desired string like one you've mentioned here : e142

Comment: //input[contains(@id,'e142')]

Comment: Tried it bro. Works fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the string "d43142e142" is constant every time, You can use following x-path to find the element ending with that string.

```
//*[ends-with(@id,"d43142e142")]
```

You can use it in code as given below.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[ends-with(@id,"d43142e142")]').click()
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[ends-with(@id,"e142")]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: i used like this: filter_field_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath='//*[ends-with(@id,"e142")]')